# Remove weekends from highcharts

Tags: javascript, c#, charts, highcharts

Is it possible to remove certain days in highcharts? I have a chart that only get data intervals from Monday to Friday. The problem Is that Saturday and Sunday is auto added to the graph even when there is no data for these days. I cant find anything that helps on [api.highcharts.com](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/) they usually have solutions to all graph related problems but I cant seem to find anything about my problem. It's probably some easy option in the chart but I cant find anything that works.
[image]

Comment: please share the array of objects which is used to create the chart

Comment: @brk I cant share the arrays and there is nothing wrong with them. Its just how highchart puts the graph together. they auto add days that are not in the array. And that is what i want to prevent from happening

Comment: you can create a new array and remove Saturday and Sunday

Comment: @brk there are no Saturday/Sundays in the array and that is what I find weird, why are they added when they dont even exist?. It maybe some settings that make highchart "force" the 7 day/week layout. But i cant find what setting that is.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, use highcharts and [breaks](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks).

> An array defining breaks in the axis, the sections defined will be left out and all the points shifted closer to each other.
>   Requires that the broken-axis.js module is loaded.

It would look something like this, in a datetime axis:

```
xAxis: {
  tickInterval: 1,
  breaks: [{
    from: 1537567200000,
    to: 1537740000000,
    breakSize: 1
  }]
}
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/L3ykegzq/

Or switch to highstock where you can have an [ordinal](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal) axis (ordinal is used by default):

> In an ordinal axis, the points are equally spaced in the chart regardless of the actual time or x distance between them. This means that missing data periods (e.g. nights or weekends for a stock chart) will not take up space in the chart. Having ordinal: false will show any gaps created by the gapSize setting proportionate to their duration.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/ordinal-true/